# VNC Viewer with No Monitor – Can't fix Resolution | Ubuntu 16.04.3

Tags: display, display-resolution, vnc

My Ubuntu machine has no monitor, I access it via Desktop Sharing. When I do, the only available resolution is 800x600.

I attempted to follow [these instructions](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/04/custom-screen-resolution-ubuntu-desktop/) I get the following message from Ubuntu: "Xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output".

Please help! Save me from this dreaded resolution :)

If I run "xrandr" with no arguments, here's the output:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080      0.00* 
   1280x1024      0.00  
   1024x768       0.00  
   800x600        0.00  
   640x480        0.00
```

Comment: What does `xrandr` say when you run it with no arguments?  Please edit the result into your question.  For example, on my headless PC, it gives `Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1024 x 768, maximum 4096 x 4096
VGA-1 disconnected primary (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)`

Comment: @OrganicMarble sorry for the late response.  I've update my question to include this information.

Comment: Hmm. It thinks it's showing 1920x1080 on a connected monitor.

Answer (score -3):

Wait for the Release of 18.04 (Bionic Beaver) , back up you're important data and perform a clean install of Bionic Beaver.

Comment: This does not fix it.